# Creating a command alias with yarn link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, jcommander

Is it possible to alias when running `yarn link`.  Specifically when `yarn link` is run [(As described here)](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-interactive-command-line-application-with-nodejs) and the `package.json name` attribute is `contacto` `yarn link` creates an executable command named `contacto`.  But what if we it to be `co` instead such that users can run `npm i contacto` and subsequently use `co` as a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's really simple.  In `package.json` just add:

```
 "bin": {"co": "./index.js"}
```

Then run `npm i -g` in the project directory and now `co` is part of your shell.